# no httpresponse when subclassing a class based view

Tags: django

I'm attempting to subclass the django-summernote view that is responsible for uploading files. The view that I want to subclass (SummernoteUploadAttachmeent) can be seen here:

https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote/blob/master/django_summernote/views.py

Within my new view, I want to run a check before the upload can happen (i.e. I want to ensure that the number uploads is less than a certain limit.

**ursl.py**

```
from .views import SummernoteUploadAttachmentwCheck

    url(r'^summernote/upload_attachment/$', SummernoteUploadAttachmentwCheck.as_view(), name='django_summernote-upload_attachment'),
```

**views.py**

```
class SummernoteUploadAttachmentwCheck(SummernoteUploadAttachment):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        user = request.user
        print(user)
        #once I'm able to get user, I will check a counter to ensure that it's under limit before allowing the rest of the function to execute.
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view jasonsproject.views.SummernoteUploadAttachmentwCheck didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
[28/Jun/2020 16:36:51] "POST /summernote/upload_attachment/ HTTP/1.1" 500 20462
```

Thanks!

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is posted in my stackoverflow post. LOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class returns None instead of HttpResponse.
Try next:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

class SummernoteUploadAttachmentwCheck(SummernoteUploadAttachment):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        user = request.user
        print(user)
        return HttpResponse('Hello :)')
```

or you can returns a template (with render(request,'template_name.html', {}), or JSON with JsonResponse... but always you need to return an instance of HttpResponse.

Comment: Thanks! As I'm subclassing this view, I assumed that the response embedded within that view would take effect. I suppose I don't understand how subclassing views works.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue is that I overrode the def post method on that view.